# How does this Raspberry Pi power circuit work?

Tags: mosfet, bjt, raspberry-pi

I looking at the Raspberry Pi schematic (Rev 3b) and found this interesting section:

[image: Rsapi3 B]

The black box is described as a diode. My understanding is that this block should perform as a diode with near zero forward voltage, but I don't fully understand how it works and what to call it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding an 'ideal' diode made from a p-channel MOSFET and PNP transistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223935/understanding-an-ideal-diode-made-from-a-p-channel-mosfet-and-pnp-transistors) Additional analysis [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/446246/11683).

Comment: I was just going to write an answer, thanks for the link. This is basically a reverse-polarity protection.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, I think about ideal diode before but mostly, it use opamp.

Comment: @PMF: No, it isn't about polarity protection at all. It's about blocking an external power supply connected on the right from back-driving the USB power, while having minimal forward voltage drop when using USB power.

Comment: it would probably also provide reverse polarity protection  up-to 5V but that's not its design purpose.